# Identity element of word addition

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, binary-operations

I realize this is rather an arbitrary question, but it's important to me, that I understand it and get it right, and I'm not finding the answer anywhere else.

I'm working through "A Book of Abstract Algebra" by Pinter and one problem set defines *binary words* and defines addition on them to be

> If a and b are both of length n then $(a_1, a_2,..., a_n) + (b_1, b_2,..., b_n) = (a_1 + b_1, a_2 + b_2,..., a_n + b_n)$

, so you add them by corresponding digits. The way you add each digit is as follows:

> $0 + 0 = 0$, $1 + 1 = 0$, $0 + 1 = 1$, $1 + 0 = 1$

There's more info the book gives about this but I think this is all that's pertinent to answer the question, but if not please correct me.

The question I'm trying to answer is what is the identity element of the operation of word addition, +, on the set of all binary words of length n, $\Bbb B^n$ ?

The answer is obviously a string of zeros but how do I properly denote this? $0_n$, or just 0, or a such that every $a_*i*$ is 0, or what?

I have the same question for the inverse. The inverse is obviously whatever the element in the set $\Bbb B_n$ is itself but how do you denote that?? Just a or $a_n$, etc.?

Comment: Why wouldn't a a strong of $0$s work? Also, the operation didn't define adding strings of different lengths. In fact, I may have been misusing the word "string." The book doesn't use that term anywhere in here. It only uses the term "word."

Comment: I thought you were using word concatenation, did not read the TeX properly. Yes, it is $0$'s.

Comment: Haha no, I've already answered that question in the book. So how would I denote that, and the inverse. Like its obviously not just one 0 or one a necessarily. Sorry, about the TeX by the way; I'm still learning how to "write math" on this site. You'd be surprised to know that I've greatly improved

Comment: As I think you pointed out, the inverse of a binary string  $a$ is $a$.

Comment: Incidentally, engineers will recognize this kind of addition simply as bitwise XOR.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I see something like the following:

> The identity element is $0^n$, a string of $n$ consecutive zeros.

The important thing here is not the $0^n$, which is an arbitrary choice of notation (and could be any of the other choices you gave, or still others), but the exposition, which explains, more or less clearly, what the identity element actually is, so that we needn't rely on the notation for everything.  Thereafter, of course, the notation can be used as a kind of shorthand for the explanation, but the first time, the explanation is important.

As André Nicolas pointed out in the comments, the inverse of $a$ is $a$ itself.

Comment: Thank you, Brian and I completely understand that the proof is more important than the notation. I don't think my book asked for one on this question so I likely just didn't concern myself with it although perhaps I should have, but it looks like the proof would be easy and I've done similar before.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think you were unclear.  Just didn't want the question to go unanswered.

Comment: I appreciate that, thank you. If you're in the business of not wanting questions to go unanswered, feel free to go to "Binary word addition; error pattern" I asked a question with that title a few weeks ago that never got a (good) answer or at least one that made sense to me anyways.